# Uniqueness of the gradient vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus

It says we can define gradient as the unique vector $\nabla f$ such that $Df(x)(v)=\langle \nabla f(x),v \rangle$

I don't understand how uniqueness is coming. I can prove uniqueness if it was given $dim(Hom(E,W))$ is finite where $f:E\subset V \to W$ and differentiable on open subset $E$ of $V$.

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that if $w_1, w_2$ are elements of an inner product space such that $\langle w_1, v\rangle = \langle w_2, v\rangle$ for all $v$, then $w_1 = w_2$.

Comment: yes that'll follow from non degeneracy but here $w_1=\nabla f_1,w_2=\nabla f_2$ right ?

Comment: There is no $f_1$ and $f_2$. The function $f$ is fixed. We are supposing that there are two vectors which satisfy the property which defines $\nabla f(x)$.

Comment: Can you please write full proof ? I'm not at all getting this thing, I need to understand it. Like, first of all how $\nabla f(x)$ is coming and then why unique

Comment: $Df(x)$ is a linear map on a finite dimensional inner product space, so it is of the form $Df(x)(v) = \langle w, v\rangle$ for some $w$; this is an application of the Reisz representation theorem. The vector $w$ is unique as I alluded to in my answer; we call the vector $w$ the gradient of $f$ at $x$, that is, we set $\nabla f(x) = w$.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be assuming that $Df(x)$ is a linear map from a vector space V with an inner product <,> to $\mathbb{R}$.  Correct, yes?  If so, then think about the connection between linear maps $V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and the inner product.  It helps to look at some more concrete cases for these problems. For example, where V is just Cartesian space $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $L:V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is linear, what would a formula for $L(x_1,x_2, x_3, ...)$ look like? Well, $$L(x_1,x_2,x_3) = 2x_1+x_2-3x_3$$.

Can you express the right-hand side as an inner product of $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and some other vector $c$?  What would $c$ be if $L(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is to be $<c,x>$?

Now think about the original question. $Df(x)$ simply denotes some linear map like $L$. Must there always be formula for $L$ like the one in the example?

Start with the above considerations and continue until done ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Found this question while thinking about the same problem as well. Actually this directly follows from [Riesz representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem), which states that every linear functional can be uniquely represented by an inner product with a vector.